# Why does my AWS REST API not delete objects in a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, http, amazon-s3, http-delete

I have an AWS REST API that is configured to delete an object in S3 bucket by HTTP DELETE request.
It is working fine, as long as the object is not inside a folder.

For example, a request 'https://a723csc6g8.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/my-bucket/photo' works, while 'https://a723csc6g8.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/my-bucket/folder/photo' does not. I get 403 error - missing autentication token.

My IAM policy has the following permissions: ListBucket, DeleteObject and DeleteObjectVersion.
Object access restriction: arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket*/*

The API json file:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "2016-10-21T17:26:28Z",
    "title" : "ApiName"
  },
  "host" : "a723csc6g8.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
  "basePath" : "/v1",
  "schemes" : [ "https" ],
  "paths" : {
    "/{bucket}/{key}" : {
      "delete" : {
        "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "key",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        }, {
          "name" : "bucket",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "200 response",
            "schema" : {
              "$ref" : "#/definitions/Empty"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions" : {
    "Empty" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "title" : "Empty Schema"
    }
  }
}
```

Has anybody encountered a similar problem?
Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues why you are "still" not allowed to delete the file, a few from the top of my head (all of these would prevent you from deleting even when IAM "allows" it):

- Bucket has ACLs enabled to prevent this
- Bucket policy prevents this
- Bucket has MFA-delete somehow enabled
- You are not the owner of the files, as they have been created by another account
- SCP, Permission Boundaries, etc.

My suggestion would be to inspect the response in detail and maybe decrypt the response if it does contain an encrypted error message. You can also check CloudTrail for authentication issues.

Comment: I'm not using ACLs, the bucket is owned by me and access is set to public. I think there is a problem in the API endpoint's URL structure, but I can't figure out where exactly.

Comment: CloudTrail is just showing me the same error message that I see in Postman: "Missing Authentication Token"